# How to upload file and rename if file is exist in folder while we keep original file name?

Tags: php, file-upload, file-rename

**Question:**

How can we upload file into folder and rename it to specific name and if file name is exist, we rename existing file inside of folder?

**For example:**

**1:** Rename file while uploading to "**update**" and keep the allowed extension.

Booking.xlsx  ---> rename ---> update.xlsx

2: If update.xlsx is exist in folder, we rename it to current time date format with extension name.

(YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD)

update.xlsx ---> rename inside folder ---> 2017-01-14T19:20:30.45+01:00.xlsx

**Here is my upload file code**:

```
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'xlsx','zip');
if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
    echo '{"status":"error"}';
    exit;
}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
    echo '{"status":"success"}';
    exit;
}
}
echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
```

**More information:**

If file name is exist, I want to rename that existing file to time date format inside of folder then upload / rename file to specific name **update**
As you know we can check if file is exist then echo a message, but how to rename existing file according to question number 2 in above.

Comment: `file_exists` - checks if file exists

Comment: One more thing: don't create json type respnses on your own. Instead use `json_encode`: `$response = ['status' => 'success']; echo json_encode($response)`;

Comment: How to rename existing file to date format ? According to question 2!

Comment: Use `rename` : http://php.net/manual/tr/function.rename.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename` method.

```
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'xlsx','zip');
if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
       echo '{"status":"error"}';
       exit;
    }
    $destination = "uploads/update.xlsx";
    if(file_exists($destination)){
        rename($destination, "uploads/" . date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP") . ".xlsx");
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $destination)){
      echo '{"status":"success"}';
      exit;
   }
}
echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
```